# Show/Hide is not working correctly in Chrome when multiple click events fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, google-chrome

The code in this example works in FF and IE 8,10, but not in Chrome.
I have an example of the code on JSFiddle.
[Bug Example](http://jsfiddle.net/huntygonecharlie/QG2ba/3/)

Here is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('button[name="IVSites"]').on('click', function () {
        //sessionStorage of button value
        sessionStorage.setItem('IVSites', $(this).val());
        var btnValue = sessionStorage.getItem('IVSites');
        switch (btnValue) {
            case "1":
                $('#site2, #site3, #site4').hide();
                $('#site1').show();
                $('#ivSiteTwo, #ivSiteThree, #ivSiteFour').removeClass('btnIVSelected');
                $('#ivSiteOne').addClass('btnIVSelected');
                break;
            case "2":
                $('#site3, #site4').hide();
                $('#site1, #site2').show();
                $('#ivSiteOne, #ivSiteThree, #ivSiteFour').removeClass('btnIVSelected');
                $('#ivSiteTwo').addClass('btnIVSelected');
                break;
            case "3":
                $('#site4').hide();
                $('#site1, #site2, #site3').show();
                $('#ivSiteOne, #ivSiteTwo, #ivSiteFour').removeClass('btnIVSelected');
                $('#ivSiteThree').addClass('btnIVSelected');
                break;
            case "4":
                $('#site1, #site2, #site3, #site4').show();
                $('#ivSiteOne, #ivSiteTwo, #ivSiteThree').removeClass('btnIVSelected');
                $('#ivSiteFour').addClass('btnIVSelected');
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

When I click on one of the four buttons, a box should display depending on the value of the button.  This works if I start at four and work backwards, but if I start at button one, the box loads, but if I click button two afterwards, the box doesn't show.  The same thing happened when I click random buttons after I made an initial click.

Example:
Click btn 4, then btn 2. This works, but click btn 3 after that and nothing happens.

I stepped through the javascript and the line that tells the box to show is getting hit in the debug tool.  There seems to be a bug with either the style attribute or the css `display:block;` the user agent is throwing into the mix.

I have tried using add/remove class instead of show/hide, but this also failed.  If anybody has a suggestion on what I can do to work around it, please clue me in to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that chrome is displaying Each `site` on top of each other when going forward..  Seems like a bug in chrome.

But one thing you can do to get around this issue is put a break `<br />` in between each `site`

e.g.

```
<br />
<article class="ivTubeCnt" id="site2" style="display:none;">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QG2ba/14/

Comment: Wow!  I would have never thought to add a <br /> to the HTML.  I did notice when I was debugging it that the article element was showing on the page as a small hidden square.  This just did not register that it was being placed behind the other element.  Thanks so much for your suggestion!